# Batch conversion from FLAC to Apple Lossless, using ffmpeg terminal command

Tags: conversion

I started using [the answer to this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26633/free-batch-conversion-from-flac-to-apple-lossless-alac) but the correct answer works only for the current directory and I would like to recurse through a tree. The answers given below the one I mention did not help. After [research about the find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), I ended up trying

```
IFS=$'\0' && for f in `find -name "*.flac"`; do ffmpeg -i "$f"  -vf "crop=((in_w/2)*2):((in_h/2)*2)" -c:a alac "${f%.flac}.m4a"; done
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and I don't understand why: the output is just a list of `./path/file.flac` but no conversion is done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about command line scripting

Comment: you're getting warm but you need to go research ffmpeg. Try getting ffmpeg to work for one file then expand on to the scripting solution.